# Can any one help me normalize this equation? (Modified 3D Gaussian)

Tags: definite-integrals, normal-distribution

$$\exp\left(
  - e^{d-sz}
  - 2 \left( \frac{z^2}{r^2f^2}+\frac{x^2+y^2}{r^2}  \right)
\right)$$

Note if this equation can't be normalized another equation with similar proprieties would also be suitable.

i.e. Gaussian Shape, and distorted by the d,s and f variable in a similar manner.

NOTE: I want to use this equation as part of a game engine, to simulate the energy released by an explosion. This explosion would be able to be focused and shaped on the z axis by the d,s and f factors and a radius of r. I then want to find/approximate (series approximation) the integral across an arbatriy spherical volume in carcassion space, the explosion will always come from the orgin, and the x,y,z will represent the dot products of the projectile/explosives direction/left/top vectors and the vector from the explosive to the center of the object to be damaged.

Comment: Take $\lim_{r\to\infty}$. The limit isn't even zero, so it definitely can't be normalized. It seems weird to refer to this as a distorted gaussian, since I can't see any values of $d,s,f$ that would make it (or at least the formula) look anything like one.

Comment: @Robert, I think it is a Gaussian in $x$, $y$, and $z$ only, while $r$ is a parameter and is not $\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$.